# Angular 2: Random Routing

Tags: angular, routes, components, angular2-routing

I'm struggling with Angular 2. I have defined all my routes, but when I type for instance "mysiteurl:4200/password-recovery" or "mysiteurl:4200/email-confirm/sometoken" it drives me randomly to home/profile Component (not desired) or to password-recovery or email-confirm Component (desired). I don't understand that redirect to the home/profile. Any ideas?

The app-routing module code:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'password-recovery', component: PasswordRecoveryComponent },
{ path: 'email-confirm/:token', component: EmailConfirmComponent },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'profile', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
        { path: 'companies', component: CompaniesComponent },
        { path: 'roles', component: RolesComponent },
        { path: 'documents/:type', component: DocumentsComponent },
        { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent },
        { path: 'documents-identity', component: DocumentsIdentityComponent },
        { path: 'forms', component: FormsComponent },
        { path: 'password-recovery-detail', component: PasswordRecoveryDetailComponent },
        { path: 'card', component: CardComponent },
    ]
}
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true })
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: You're configured to `useHash` for your navigation. So to navigate use hash approach: `mysiteurl:4200/#/password-recovery`

Comment: It doesn't affect the result.. Sometimes password-recovery, sometimes home/profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault, I was forcing the navigation to /home/profile in the bootstrapped component